# Error linking libboost_system in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2005, boost-asio

I have a problem using boost.asio. I use Windows XP and Visual Studio 2005

I followed these steps:

- I downloaded the latest version (http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.46.1/) of W: \boost_1_46_1
- I set the environment variable `INCLUDE : W:\boost_1_46_1`
- In the properties of my project `(VS->tools->Options project&solutions->vcc++directories)` I added `$(INCLUDE)`
- I added in my file. h this:
- I get the following error:

  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc80-mt-gd-1_46_1.lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boost::asio library needs to be built. ( Many other boost 'libraries are headers only and do not need to be built ).  Building it yourself is a small challenge.  Better to use the pre-built binary installer which is [here](http://www.boostpro.com/products/free)

Once you have the built libraries, one way or another, you have to tell the linker where they are.  However, you do not need to specify each individual library by name, just specify the folder that contains them.  The easiest way to do this IMHO is to create an environment variable called BOOSTROOT which you you set equal to the folder where you installed boost.  Then you tell the linker to look for libraries in $(BOOSTROOT)/lib

Comment: +1 On windows VS boost uses autolinking. Adding the lib in the additional dependencies is unnecessary. Your problem is that you haven't built boost yet. Use the installer as ravenspoint advised.

Comment: @Ralf while you do not need to tell linker where individual libraries are, you do need to tell it where the folder containing the libraries is located.  I explain how in the body of my answer.

Comment: then:
- in C:\Programmi\boost\boost_1_46_1 i have libraries boost , I have also ibboost_system-vc80-mt-gd-1_46_1.lib
- I set a environment variable $ (INCLUDE) with the path of these lib
- I set this in Visual Studio 2005 to include:
VS->tools->Options project&solutions->vcc++directories) I added $ (INCLUDE)

I'm always the error: LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc80-mt-gd-1_46_1.lib'
how can I fix this?

Comment: @GgSalent You need to tell the linker where the libraries are located.  Your comment describes telling the compiler where to find the header files, which is necessary, but does not help the linker.  Please try to follow the recipe I suggested in my answer, using $(BOOSTROOT).

Answer (score 4):

This is a linker error. Find the lib, and go to linker input, and add it there. Be sure to set the libpath as well. This picture should guide you:

[image]